# \pagetotal slightly off

Tags: vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

I have a text and its translation. I would like to have the original text on the left page, and the translation on the right and have them vertically positioned so that the first line of the translation is aligned with the last line of the original.

What i did is I created a legnth, and set its value to `\pagetotal` on the second-to-last line of the original text. I then used a `\vspace` to add that much white space on top of the second page. This almost works, but for some reason, it is very slightly off. I assume that the problem is in how exactly `\pagetotoal` is measure, which suggests, it should be fixable by manipulating the value, but I have no idea how...

How should I manipulate the length so that the lines perfectly vertically aligned?

here is an exmaple of my code:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}

\usepackage[a6paper, margin=0.35in]{geometry}

\newlength{\pagetandem}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{8\baselineskip}

    \vspace*{1\baselineskip}
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\global\setlength{\pagetandem}{\pagetotal}

    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

    \newpage

    \vspace*{\pagetandem}
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compute `\pagetotal` between paragraphs, but also add `\prevdepth` (the depth of the last line) and subtract `\topskip` and `\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper, margin=0.1cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% just for better view

\newlength{\pagetandem}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{9\baselineskip}

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\hfill AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\hfill AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\hfill AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\hfill AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\hfill yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

\setlength{\pagetandem}{\dimeval{\pagetotal+\prevdepth-\topskip-\baselineskip}}

\newpage

\vspace*{\pagetandem}

BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

\end{document}
```

I made the margin very narrow and `\parindent` to zero to better see the alignment.

[image]